# Is it a right way to store values in session

Tags: asp.net, session

**Is it a right way to store values in session object** ?

I tried it but didn't worked correctly.
I mean, the values, which are stored in sessions are not correctly accessible or stored.
Can anyone help me with this problem?
Thank you.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {            
                if (Session["cart_table"] == null)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new Spcart().GetCart();
                    Session["cart_table"] = dt;                 
                }

                if (Session["ptax"] == null)
                {
                    Session["ptax"] = 0;
                }
                if (Session["subtotal"] == null)
                {
                    Session["subtotal"] = 0;
                }

                  BindCartListView();
              }
         }

 public void BindCartListView()
    {
        -----------------------              //some code 

        int tax=100;
        int total=300;
        int[] totals;
        totals = bindtotal(tax, total); 

        -----------------------------------     //some code 
    }

 public int[] bindtotal(int tax, int total)
    {

        int ptax = (int)Session["ptax"];
        ptax += tax;
        Session["ptax"] = ptax;

        int subtotal = (int)Session["subtotal"];
        subtotal += total;
        Session["ptax"] = subtotal;

        int granttotal = ptax + subtotal;
        Session["granttotal"] = granttotal;

        int[] totals = { subtotal, granttotal };
        return totals;
    }
```

Comment: The code you've posted looks correct, as far as it goes.  What isn't working exactly?

Comment: @dbaseman : sometimes the session["ptax"] & session["subtotal"] values becomes zero & sometimes these vales different as want/should b                                        on page load

Comment: you are initializing the session values to 0 on the first page load (assuming these variables are only used in this page)

Comment: I only see where you are setting values into the session. Where are you reading values from the session? (apart from when you read them in order to update them)

Comment: I noticed that you set Session["ptax"] twice. Perhaps that is the problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ya it seems to be correct ,but if it is giving any error ,then please post that error..otherwise it looks OK